# Hyperlinks not working in PDFView (in my cocoa app)

Tags: cocoa, pdf, pdfkit

I have a PDFView object in one of my windows and wondering if there's anything special I need to do in order for the hyperlinks to work.

The same pdf files have working hyperlinks when opened in other apps (like skim, preview, etc).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that I simply had to enable this in my derived class: [super mouseDown:theEvent];

Answer (score 1):

Add a delegate to your PDFView that responds to this selector

```
- (void)PDFViewWillClickOnLink:(PDFView *)sender withURL:(NSURL *)url
{
   [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, closed the issue - see below.